# d3.js Force Directed Graph Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, analytics, visualization

I am getting the following error in the dev console any time i try to spin up my code. Errors below:

```
    Error: missing: 1 3d-force-graph:5:22166
    TypeError: r.attributes.position is undefine
```

Live version of erroneous code seen here:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/mnas/index.html

Actual code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <style> body { margin: 0; } </style>
   <script src="//unpkg.com/3d-force-graph"></script>
  <!--<script src="3d-force-graph.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="3d-graph"></div>

  <script>
    const elem = document.getElementById('3d-graph');
    const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
      (elem)
    .graphData({"nodes":[{ "name": "Myriel","group":  1 },{ "name": "Napoleon","group":  1 }], links: [ { "source":  1,  "target":  2,  "value":  1 }]})
        .nodeLabel('id')
        .nodeAutoColorBy('group')
        .onNodeHover(node => elem.style.cursor = node ? 'pointer' : null)
     .onNodeClick(node => {
          // Aim at node from outside it
          const distance = 40;
          const distRatio = 1 + distance/Math.hypot(node.x, node.y, node.z);

          Graph.cameraPosition(
            { x: node.x * distRatio, y: node.y * distRatio, z: node.z * distRatio }, // new position
            node, // lookAt ({ x, y, z })
            3000  // ms transition duration
          );
        });
  </script>
</body>
```

This is a fork of the following code:
https://github.com/vasturiano/3d-force-graph/blob/master/example/click-to-focus/index.html

The only thing I changed is that I replaced the jsonUrl method so that I can pass through static data instead.

I've tried debugging via Dev Console and can't seem to figure out the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing "id" attribute

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
  <style> body { margin: 0; } </style>
   <script src="//unpkg.com/3d-force-graph"></script>
  <!--<script src="3d-force-graph.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="3d-graph"></div>

  <script>
    const elem = document.getElementById('3d-graph');
    const Graph = ForceGraph3D()
      (elem)
    .graphData({"nodes":[{ "name": "Myriel","group":  1, "id" : 1},{ "name": "Napoleon","group":  1, "id": 2 }], links: [ { "source":  1,  "target":  2,  "value":  1 }]})
        .nodeLabel('name')
        .nodeAutoColorBy('group')
        .onNodeHover(node => elem.style.cursor = node ? 'pointer' : null)
     .onNodeClick(node => {
          // Aim at node from outside it
          const distance = 40;
          const distRatio = 1 + distance/Math.hypot(node.x, node.y, node.z);

          Graph.cameraPosition(
            { x: node.x * distRatio, y: node.y * distRatio, z: node.z * distRatio }, // new position
            node, // lookAt ({ x, y, z })
            3000  // ms transition duration
          );
        });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You are awesome and so helpful Umesh! I had a feeling it was something silly like that. I had been looking at a screen for so long that I wasn't able to see that the problem was very much right in  front of my face. Thank you!